# Windows server shared printer appears on search but doesnt exist on server

Tags: windows-server-2016, print-server

A deleted printer HER_W001 appears on AD search, filtered by location HER

[AD Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBVKl.png)

Although this printer doesn't exist on the server anymore.

[Print Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lba9w.png)

How to solve this?